# Problems with exporting using Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Cloud Functions with Javascript, but I'm having this error with the `import` and `export` statements. How can I replace them?

```
const firebase = require('firebase');

const config = {
    apiKey: *****,
    authDomain: *****,
    databaseURL: *****,
    projectId: *****,
    storageBucket: *****,
    messagingSenderId: *****
};

const fire = firebase.initializeApp(config);    

export { fire };
```

Comment: What is the problem?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase JavaScript functions doesn't support ES6 `import/export`. Is uses CommonJS.

You have to attach the functions you want to export to the `exports` object instead:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.yourFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: It does support it now. In package.json
Add 
  "type": "module",
& add
 "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^3.3.0"
as dependency